# How would I clone an entry in a column to all with same ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking to clone an entry in a database while the id is the same.

Each line has its own ID, and then a separate column for the entry I'm looking to duplicate. I'm trying to find any entry with data in this column, and clone it to any other lines with the same ID.

Example:

```
ID      COLUMNNAME
1       Test 1
1      
2       
2       Test 2
3
3
```

In this case, Test 1 would clone to the line below, and Test 2 would clone to the line above, while ID 3 would stay blank.

I have:

```sql
SELECT `columnname`, `id`
FROM `table`
WHERE `columnname` <> ''
    AND `id` = `id`
```

written up to find the entries with data, but unsure where to go from here as I'm still very new to MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a self-join with the mulitple-table `UPDATE` syntax:

```
UPDATE my_table t1 JOIN my_table t2 ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND t2.columnname <> ''
SET    t1.columnname = t2.columnname
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/31122/1/0).

Comment: Ahh perfect, didn't realise a join would work within the same table - Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Or a Subquery

```
Update t1
       Set t1.ColumnName = (Select Min(t2.ColumnName) From my_table t2 Where t2.ID = t1.ID And t2.ColumnName <> '')
FROM dbo.my_table t1
       Where t1.ColumnName = '' Or t1.ColumnName IS NULL
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5fb81/5

But, the self-join solution is much cleaner and faster.